# Floating Widget? Floating Button? Don't know what it's called

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]

I'm trying to implement a feature like the one in the image. (I'm working with Kotlin)
I want a button that works even when the app is not on the screen.
It's just that I'm not sure what it's called so I've been having difficulties finding information about the feature.
Floating widget or floating button seems to be similar to the feature that I'm looking for, but I'm not too sure. Can anyone tell me what this feature is called?

Comment: You may need to create app widgets: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets

Comment: @noahutz Thanks for the suggestion! I think that might be the one that I've been looking for